# Passing Unicode to BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup

Basically I want to know if I can do something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

unicode_text = u'\u266a Here is some unicode text \u266a'
soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode_text)
```

I'm currently writing a module that takes in a Unicode string, uses BeautifulSoup4 to parse/modify the string, then return the result (still as Unicode). My question is whether BeautifulSoup4 allows for you to pass in Unicode strings to parse. The [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) only mention that bs4 will detect the encoding of a byte string(possibly using chardet, [which raises an error if passed a Unicode string](https://github.com/chardet/chardet/blob/master/chardet/__init__.py#L22)) and automatically convert that string to Unicode, but it never mentions anything about passing in Unicode. From just running some basic tests it looks like I can just pass Unicode in and modify it and it doesn't raise any errors or anything, but I'd like to know if there is a more definitive answer?

Comment: If it works it works is what the definitive answer is. If theres nothing in the documentation and you try it and it works, then you should be ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after finally looking at the source code for bs4, I can say that it is safe to pass Unicode to BeautifulSoup.

bs4 uses a module called [UnicodeDammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) to detect and convert the text you pass to it. The [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/dammit.py) (lines 342-347) states that the character encoding detection short-circuits if the text is already Unicode. This is also true regardless of whether you have [cchardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/) or [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) installed in your environment